# Probability Theory - Fair dice

Tags: probability-theory

Three fair six-sided dice are thrown and the dice show three different numbers.  Find the probability that at least one six is obtained.

Im unsure ofwhat type of question this is, I have tried combinations such as 6C1 over 18C3.

But im not sure if this is correct.  Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The number of possible outcomes of this experiment is given by
$$
\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{3!}.
$$
Outcomes when no $6$ is obtained is given by
$$
\frac{5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{3!}.
$$
The probability that at least one $6$ is obtained
$$
1-\frac{\frac{5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{3!}}{\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{3!}}=\frac12.
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are $N=\binom{6}{3}=6C3=C_6^3 = 20$ total triplets with different numbers.

There are $M=\binom{5}{2}=5C2=C_5^2 = 10$ these triplets with one six.

---

Full list:

$1,2,3$
$1,2,4$
$1,2,5$
$1,2,6$ *
$1,3,4$
$1,3,5$
$1,3,6$ *
$1,4,5$
$1,4,6$ *
$1,5,6$ *

$2,3,4$
$2,3,5$
$2,3,6$ *
$2,4,5$
$2,4,6$ *
$2,5,6$ *

$3,4,5$
$3,4,6$ *

$4,5,6$ *

Comment: Simpler: half of the numbers show up, so the probability a 6 shows up is ....

Comment: @GerryMyerson, really. nice.